# Sencha touch 2 Proxy writer and model mapping

Tags: mapping, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my model, the fields are using a mapping to get the data from a Get request in json.

```
{name: 's35_193', type: 'int', mapping: 'oa$ext.od$document.od$fields.od$field[2].od$value[0].$t'}
```

I have a root defined in my proxy reader and writer : 'entry'

In post request, to save my model instance, this mapping is not kept. I modify the value of the s35_193 field and when I save the model instance with a post I get this in the request body

```
{"entry":{"s35_193":1342735200005} .....  }
```

How can I change the way the model proxy writer is encoding the field to keep the mapping ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

For information I created a new writer and I overrided the getRecordData() method.

There I can write the object I want.

Hope it will help someone :)